# Why isn't Word splitting my table?

Tags: microsoft-word

Pls see GIF below. I pointed my cursor at the 2nd row of the table, but clicking 'Split Table' didn't split it there.

[image]

Comment: Works fine in Office 2019. What are your Windows & Office versions and could you post an example document?

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for replying as usual. I just re-attempted it and now it works! Strange.

Comment: If whatever it was has now disappeared, there can be no answer.